# Adding multiple Resource Dictionaries dynamic to my WPF-Project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

I need some help with Resource Dictionaries in WPF. I have multiple .dll's and in each dll are one or more Resource Dictionaries. The problem is I dont know the name or the location from the Resource Dictionaries in the DLL. Now Im looking for a way to add all these Resource Dictionaries in the Code Behind in my Main.xaml

Maybe something with reflection in the assembly?

```
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
resourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary2 = new ResourceDictionary();
resourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("Dictionary2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

resourceDictionary2.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);

Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary2);
```

But it only add 1 Resource Dictionary... Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, somehting was buggy in my project. I did a new clean project and tried different solutions and the solution from tabby worked . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
{
     Source = new Uri("Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
};

ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary2 = new ResourceDictionary
{
     Source = new Uri("Dictionary2.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
};

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary );
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary2 );
```

Comment: do you get any exception?

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is wrong. Try

```
//Load #1 ResourceDictionary
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
resourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

//Load #2 ResourceDictionary
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary2 = new ResourceDictionary();
resourceDictionary2.Source = new Uri("Dictionary2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

//Merge #1 & #2 
resourceDictionary2.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);

//Add to Resources
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary2);
```